# Securely storing connection strings in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is storing connection strings in web.config the most secure solution? Is there a way to store them on the server to which they are deployed to, instead (as a system DSN, for example, though I believe those are cumbersome)?.

I'm moving my work codebase to BitBucket, and for some reason am extremely uncomfortable with the idea of having a web.config that contains a database username/password on a machine that I don't have draconian control over. I may just be acting irrationally; never hosted any code externally.

Comment: Have you considered integrated security? Then your connection string don't have to contain such sensitive information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encrypt sections of your web.config. You could do that for the ConnectionStrings Section. MSDN link available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the security of your connection strings you have the possibility to [encrypt them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think this case is overblown. ASP.Net by default will never serve your web.config file no matter how hard a determined hacker tries to get it.

Comment: The question is: when a hacker gets access to the computer through some other hole, what will he or she find? A username and password in the clear? Great, now they have easy access to all your data too.

Comment: Regardless, it never hurts to have defense-in-depth mechanisms.